# Configure custom "root" directory with "babel-plugin-module-resolver"?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, babel-plugin, babel-plugin-module-resolver

Here is my project structure:

```
cloudRun
  distApp          // TRANSPILED APP FILES FROM ./src
  distService      // TRANSPILED BACKEND FILES FROM ./cloudRun/src
  src              // SOURCE FILES FOR THE BACKEND CODE
    index.js       // INDEX.JS FOR THE BACKEND CODE
  babel.config.js  // CONFIG FOR THE BABEL TRANSPILE SCRIPT
src                // SOURCE FILES FOR THE APP
  index.js         // INDEX.JS FOR THE APP CODE
package.json       // THIS IS THE MAIN PROJECT package.json
```

I'll try to be very succinct and clear.

In both of the `index.js` (app and backend code) I use **path aliases** in the source code.

For example:

`./src/some-folder/some-file.js`

```
import xxx from "@src/hooks/someHoot";

// IN THE TRANSPILED VERSION @src MUST BE CONVERTED TO ./cloudRun/distApp
```

And also, for example:

`./cloudRun/src/some-folder/some-file.js`

```
import xxx from "@src/hooks/someHoot";

// IN THE TRANSPILED VERSION @src MUST BE CONVERTED TO ./cloudRun/distApp
```

But somehow I'm having trouble when configuring `module-resolver` on `babel.config.js`. Either I get it to work correctly with the path aliases present on `./src` (and path aliases on `./cloudRun/src` are all wrong by 1 level) or vice-versa.

For example:

`.cloudRun/babel.config.js`

```
plugins = [
  ["module-resolver", {
    "alias": {
      "@src"   : "./distApp",
      "@hooks" : "./distApp/hooks",
    }
  }]
];
```

This works for the `./src` files. But files from `./cloudRun/src` are all wrong by 1 level up.

And if I change to this:

`.cloudRun/babel.config.js`

```
plugins = [
  ["module-resolver", {
    "alias": {
      "@src"   : "./cloudRun/distApp",
      "@hooks" : "./cloudRun/distApp/hooks",
    }
  }]
];
```

Then it works fine for the `./cloudRun/src` files. But all files from `./src` will be wrong by 1 level down.

I was thinking that I might fix this with the `"root"` option in the [module-resolver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-module-resolver) config. But I couldn't make it work yet.

Maybe something like this:

`.cloudRun/babel.config.js`

```
plugins = [
  ["module-resolver", {
    "root": ["./cloudRun"],               // SET A NEW ROOT HERE
    "alias": {
      "@src"   : "./distApp",
      "@hooks" : "./distApp/hooks",
    }
  }]
];
```

I've tried many things inside the `"root"` config. But so far it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Here is how I run babel:

```
// SCRIPTS FROM ./package.json

babel src --out-dir cloudRun/distApp --config-file ./cloudRun/babel.config.js

babel cloudRun/src --out-dir cloudRun/distService --config-file ./cloudRun/babel.config.js
```

Comment: Any resolution to this issue?